# Dynamic Swapping of tags in html using angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to dynamically add/remove html tags based on the response coming from a service. This is similar to a if-else condition. If any response is coming from the service I will be display the response or else I will be displaying a default option. I am not understanding how to achieve this. I got to know that we can use  to show/hide something. Is this a proper way to achieve this?

```
<ng-template #showBlock>
  <p>
    Show this only if "show" is true
  </p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #notShowBlock>
  <p>
    Show this only if "show" is not true
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work... you can set an input to toggle the values so that you see the effects upfront

relevant **HTML**:

```
select to toggle<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showNgTemplate" /> {{showNgTemplate}} <br/>
<div class='ngTemplateSection'>
  <ng-template *ngIf='showNgTemplate then showBlock else notShowBlock'>
  </ng-template>
</div>

<ng-template #showBlock> 
  <p>
    Show this only if "show" is true
  </p>
</ng-template> 
<ng-template #notShowBlock>
  <div class='warningStatement'>
    <p>
      Show this only if "show" is not true
    </p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

check [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h62fek?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

If you got response from server API means just simply return

```
public async Task<int>UpdateValue(modelname obj)
{
if(needtoshow){
return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

Based on above condition if you used in TS response after the subscribe method

```
this.getmethos(modelvalues).subcribe(res=>{
if(res){
  -- wrote your condition to show
}else{
  -- wrote based on response false hide the html tag 
}

})
```